# How can we have table grouping in Spark the same way as SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In SQL Server we have a database, inside database we have schema and under that schema we have table, like `DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`. And we also refer to Database as Catalog in SQL Server.

But in Spark, Catalog means an interface that we use to interact with Spark. I also noticed same result when I typed

- `spark.sql('show databases').show()` and
- `spark.sql('show schemas').show()`

Does database and schema mean same thing in Spark? If not what's the difference? In Spark, is it possible to have it the same way like SQL server has `DatabaseName.Schema.TableName`?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs

> Please note that the usage of SCHEMAS and DATABASES are
> interchangeable and mean the same thing.

[SHOW DATABASES](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-databases.html#:%7E:text=SHOW%20DATABASES%201%20Description%20Lists%20the%20databases%20that,filter%20the%20results%20of%20the%20%20statement.%20)

And [CREATE TABLE](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html) supports only two-part names.